# logging problem with eclipse Neon.1a Release (4.6.1) on Ubuntu 16.10 works fine on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: virtualbox, eclipse, 16.10

When starting eclipse Neon.1a Release (4.6.1) on Ubuntu 16.10 I get the **assertion messages** below, same binary works fine on Ubuntu 16.04. I'm running the OS on latest version of virtual box under windows 10

> SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. SLF4J: Found
>   binding in
>   [bundleresource://514.fwk1968751179:1/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in
>   [bundleresource://514.fwk1968751179:2/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an
>   explanation. SLF4J: Actual binding is of type
>   [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
>
> (Eclipse:4348): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in
>   != NULL' failed
>
> (Eclipse:4348): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in
>   != NULL' failed
>
> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger
>   (org.eclipse.jubula.client.core.ClientTestImpl). log4j:WARN Please
>   initialize the log4j system properly.

Comment: We have the same problem here. Have you ever contacted the eclipse forum? I think the people there may understand the problem better, because it seems for me to be an eclipse based problem and not an Ubuntu based problem.